# "Deinterlacing" a list in Scala

Tags: list, scala, partitioning

I have a list of bytes that represent raw samples read in from an audio interface. Depending on the use case and H/W, each sample can be anywhere from 1 to 4 bytes long, and the total number of channels in the "stream" can be more or less arbitrary. The amount of channels and bits per sample are both known at runtime.

I'll give an example of what I mean. There are four channels in the stream and each sample is two bytes.

`List(A1, A2, B1, B2, C1, C2, D1, D2, A3, A4, B3, B4, C3, C4, D3, D4)`

so `A1` is the first byte of channel *A*'s first sample, `A2` is the second byte of the same sample and so on.

What I need to do is extract each channel's samples into their own lists, like this:

`List(List(A1, A2, A3, A4), List(B1, B2, B3, B4), List(C1, C2, C3, C4), List(D1, D2, D3, D4))`

How would I go about doing this in idiomatic Scala? I just started learning Scala a few hours ago, and the only non-imperative solution I've come up with is clearly nonoptimal:

```
def uninterleave(samples: Array[Byte], numChannels: Int, bytesPerSample: Int) = {
val dropAmount = numChannels * bytesPerSample
  def extractChannel(n: Int) = {
    def extrInner(in: Seq[Byte], acc: Seq[Byte]): Seq[Byte] = {
      if(in == List()) acc
      else extrInner(in.drop(dropAmount), in.take(bytesPerSample) ++ acc)
    }
    extrInner(samples.drop(n * bytesPerSample), Nil)
  }

  for(i <- 0 until numChannels) yield extractChannel(i)
}
```

Comment: Be aware that lists are not the most efficient way to store bytes.  Hopefully this doesn't matter, since if you're trying to do something quickly, you'll have to do a lot more work by hand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would do

```
samples.grouped(bytesPerSample).grouped(numChannels).toList
  .transpose.map(_.flatten)
```

I would not vouch for its performance though. I would rather avoid lists, unfortunately `grouped` produces them.

Maybe

```
samples.grouped(bytesPerSample).map(_.toArray)
  .grouped(numChannels).map(_.toArray)
  .toArray
  .transpose
  .map(flatten)
```

Still, lots of lists.

Comment: Cool, very stylish and compact!

Comment: I understand how and why this works, but what I _don't_ understand is how you guys come up with insanely clever solutions like this.

I suppose all those years of Java and C++ have really taken their toll on my brain

Comment: First `grouped` was rather obvious, second one not too far away. Noticing this was a `transpose` was lucky. Part of the answer might be the plural in "you guys". Maybe some people find a short solution each time, I certainly do not (done my years of java too. still do).

Comment: I can vouch for its performance. It is 15% faster than the second version!

Comment: also the last line of the second would need to be `.map(_.flatten).asInstanceOf[Array[Array[Byte]]]` otherwise you get an `Array[Array[Nothing]]`

Answer (score 6):

[didierd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754787/didierd)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992429/deinterlacing-a-list-in-scala/7992769#7992769) is just about perfect, but, alas, I think one *can* improve it a bit. He is concerned with all the list creation, and transpose is a rather heavy operation as well. If you can process all the data at the same time, it might well be good enough.

However, I'm going with `Stream`, and use a little trick to avoid transposing.

First of all, the grouping is the same, only I'm turning stuff into streams:

```
def getChannels[T](input: Iterator[T], elementsPerSample: Int, numOfChannels: Int) =
  input.toStream.grouped(elementsPerSample).toStream.grouped(numOfChannels).toStream
```

Next, I'll give you a function to extract *one* channel from that:

```
def streamN[T](s: Stream[Stream[Stream[T]]])(channel: Int) = s flatMap (_(channel))
```

With those, we can decode the streams like this:

```
// Sample input
val input = List('A1, 'A2, 'B1, 'B2, 'C1, 'C2, 'D1, 'D2, 'A3, 'A4, 'B3, 'B4, 'C3, 'C4, 'D3, 'D4)

// Save streams to val, to avoid recomputing the groups
val streams = getChannels(input.iterator, elementsPerSample = 2, numOfChannels = 4)

// Decode each one
def demuxer = streamN(streams) _
val aa = demuxer(0)
val bb = demuxer(1)
val cc = demuxer(2)
val dd = demuxer(3)
```

This will return separate streams for each channel *without* having the whole stream at hand. This might be useful if you need to process the input in real time. Here's some input source to test how far into the input it reads to get at a particular element:

```
def source(elementsPerSample: Int, numOfChannels: Int) = Iterator.from(0).map { x =>
  "" + ('A' + x / elementsPerSample % numOfChannels).toChar +
  (x % elementsPerSample 
   + (x / (numOfChannels * elementsPerSample)) * elementsPerSample 
   + 1)
}.map { x => println("Saw "+x); x }
```

You can then try stuff like this:

```
val streams = getChannels(source(2, 4), elementsPerSample = 2, numOfChannels = 4)
def demuxer = streamN(streams) _
val cc = demuxer(2)
println(cc take 20 toList)
val bb = demuxer(1)
println(bb take 30 toList)
```

Comment: What do you mean, 'alas'? I like it with streams.

Comment: Interestingly enough this is very close to the actual use case of the function in question.

I'm a bit fuzzy on on what the flatMap bit exactly does, though. Guess I'll have to spend some tinkering in REPL

Comment: @tomek In monadic terms, say you have a type `M[A]`, and function `f: A => M[B]`. `flatMap(f)` will then return `M[B]`, whereas `map` return `M[M[B]]`. You may also think of it as `map(f).flatten`.